# Understanding thread-safety

Tags: thread-safety, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Let use as example standard Binary Search Tree, its nodes having an encapsulated value and pointers to the left and right children and its parent. Its primary methods are `addNode()`, `removeNode()` and `searchNode()`.

I want to understand how to make my data structure safe. I however do not know much about thread-safety and want to ask if what I am thinking is correct or not.

My first problem is one of decision: what I want to happen when I have concurrent methods? Let us say I am using my BST to manage a map in a game: the position of the character of a player is represented by an array of `double`s, I store the player's positions in my BST in lexicographic order. One player destroyed a target (and his thread want to remove it from my map), but another player is initiating an attack and needs a list of all possible targets inside a certain distance from him, including the target just removed (and his thread want to execute a search that will include the target). How I manage the situation? What about other situations?

My second problem, (I think) my biggest, is one of actuation: how I make happen what I want to happen. I read about things like atomic-operations, linearity, obstruction-free, lock-free, wait-free. I never found out in a single place a simple definition for each, the advantages of that strategy, the disadvantages. What are those things? What am I doing if I am locking the nodes, or if i am locking the *pointers* to other nodes, or the values encapsulates in the node?

Am I understanding correctly the problematics of thread-safety? Do you have suggestions on problems I should think about, or on written papers and pdfs I should read in order to better understand the problems and their many solutions?